# curl truncating parts of query strings?

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

So I'm trying to get about several hundred spiders running on an EC2 instance through Scrapyd. I've got a ton of URLs like this one:

```
https://items.initrode.com/TGWebHost/searchitems.aspx?partnerid=25233&siteid=5296
```

But when I run the spider via CURL...

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=MYPROJECT -d spider=SOMESPIDER -d spider_specific_option=1 -d url="https://items.initrode.com/TGWebHost/searchitems.aspx?partnerid=25233&siteid=5296"
```

...and check the start_urls list on my spider, the URL I passed in seems to be missing the &siteid value, like so:

```
https://items.initrode.com/TGWebHost/searchitems.aspx?partnerid=2523
```

After hours of research I've discovered that curl stops processing at the '&' character and thinks you're trying to shove this process into the background, which I observed it does, and the end result is that I'm missing a part of the query string.

I've managed to get around this problem by replacing the & in all my URLs with a %26 instead, but why did curl interpret it like that when the URL was already in quotes in the first place? I thought the quotes were supposed to prevent a problem like this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and `curl` in the case of the `-d` option indeed interprets `&` as a delimiter and therefore you can't use it there and need to excape it properly. In python you could do this using `urllib.parse.quote()` and the result would look like the following:

```
https%3A//items.initrode.com/TGWebHost/searchitems.aspx%3Fpartnerid%3D25233%26siteid%3D5296
```

Then you would run curl as follows:

```
curl 'http://localhost:6800/schedule.json' \
    -d project=MYPROJECT \
    -d spider=SOMESPIDER \
    -d spider_specific_option=1 \
    -d "url=https%3A//items.initrode.com/TGWebHost/searchitems.aspx%3Fpartnerid%3D25233%26siteid%3D5296"
```

So the problem is not in the shell quoting as I originally suggested, and it's not strictly in the way `curl` interprets the argument, but more in the way the query string is interpretted on the server side where `&` needs to be interpreted as the delimiter.

Comment: I did make a few edits to the post above, I missed the command line url though. So what you're saying is i need to enclose it in ' single quotes and not " double quotes?